# How many balls spill in expectation? (balls and bins)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expected-value, balls-in-bins

Consider throwing $n$ balls uniformly into $k$ bins, each of *capacity* $c$.

Denoting by $X_i$ the number of balls thrown to bin $i$, I'm interested in understanding the quantity
$$S_{n,k,c}=\sum_{i=1}^k\max(0,X_i-c)\qquad,$$
which is the number of balls that spill from the bins.

> What is known about $S_{n,k,c}$? Can we upper bound its expectation? What about the variance?

---

It seems easy to write an explicit formula for the expectation:
$$
\mathbb E[S_{n,k,c}]=k\sum_{j=c+1}^n\Pr[X_i=j]\cdot(j-c)=k\sum_{j=c+1}^n{n\choose j}k^{-j}(1-1/k)^{n-j}(j-c)\quad{},
$$
but I'm hoping for a bound that's easier to work with.